Does a processing architecture exist that parallelises division operations?
I understand that while multiplication and division operations require similar compute power, multiplication can be parallelised per operation, meaning that using more transistors* in parallel to get the job done faster.
Do processor architectures look to collect division operations into parallelisable sets (32 or 64 say) that would effectively equalise multiplication and division performance? I would imagine, again notionally, that this would amount to a similar die area, power, transistor count etc. used for each of multiplication and division operations.
If they do/did, how would a desktop programmer access such things or would they be hidden by the operating system?
*Notionally, i.e. all proportional to electrical/thermal power, die area etc.

Absolutely. An ARM M1 processor has a reasonably long latency for division (maybe 11 cycles) but a throughput of one division every three cycles. And twice that with vector instructions. It's not the same performance as multiplication, but then division takes more time by a constant factor. Typically to divide x / y, you have one instruction calculating a 10 or 12 bit approximation to 1/y, possible using a table lookup, followed by 3 steps of Newton iteration getting 1/y with full precision, and one multiplication x * (1 / y). An some very, very, very careful design to keep the maximum error small enough.
It also has some considerable out-of-order capabilities. So a chain of fifty dependent divisions will take 500 or 600 cycles, but if you then start another independent chain it will work completely in parallel.
